# SpringBoot WebMvcConfigurer.addInterceptors()

Tags: java, spring-boot

in SpringBoot2.0.0.RELESAEversion

use WebMvcConfigurer configure MyWebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class MyMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

     @Override
     public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
           registry.addInterceptor(new TestHandlerInterceptors()).addPathPatterns("/**");
     }
}


public class TestHandlerInterceptors implements HandlerInterceptor {
   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
       return false;   
   }

   @Override
   public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

   }

   @Override
   public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

static resource cannot be loaded when **preHandle** method returning **false**

Comment: Because that is what `false` indicates, stop processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`, you can extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` Which will give you default implementation.
For static resources, you can override as below.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations(new String[] {"classpath:/","classpath:/public/"});
}
```

Comment: In Spring 5 you should implement WebMvcConfigurer instead as it now has default method implementations:  
  
_"as of 5.0 WebMvcConfigurer has default methods (made possible by a Java 8 baseline) and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter"_  
  
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html

Comment: yep, in fact WebMvcConfigurerAdapter has been deprecated